# Probability to choose orange juice for the mix

Tags: probability, probability-theory, binomial-coefficients

Drinks are mixed at a children's party. There are 8 different fruit juices available.

From these 8 fruit juices, 3 different fruit juices are selected in equal parts
to be mixed.

(a) State how many different drinks can be mixed in this way.

One of the 8 fruit juices that can be selected is orange juice. In the course of a game
each blindfolded child chooses 3 different ones independently of the other blindfolded children
to mix them into a drink. (Any selection of 3 fruit juices has the equal chance of being selected.)

(b) Calculate the probability p that orange juice was chosen for the drink.

10 children take part in this game.

(c) Calculate the probability that at least 2 of the 10 children will choose orange juice for
the drink.

$$$$

For (a) I have done the following :

There are $\binom{8}{3}=56$ different mixed juices.

Could you give me a hint for (b)  ?

At (c) we have $P(X\geq 2)=1-P(X<2)$ and this probability is related to $p$ of part (b), right?

Comment: If a child selects orange juice, then that child must also select two of the other seven juices.  Your approach to part (c) is correct.

Comment: Do you mean $p=\frac{1}{8}\cdot \frac{1}{7}\cdot \frac{1}{6}$ ? @N.F.Taussig

Comment: I mean that the number of ways a child can select three juices  if orange juice is one of those three juices is $\binom{1}{1}\binom{7}{2}$.  Compare this with the number of ways of selecting three juices without restriction.

Answer (score 1):

You did the first part correctly.  To calculate the probability that a child selects orange juice, observe that she or he must select orange juice and two of the other seven juices, which can be done in
$$\binom{1}{1}\binom{7}{2} = \binom{7}{2}$$
ways.  Dividing this by the number of ways a child could select three juices without restriction gives you the probability that a child selects orange juice.  Your approach for the third part of the problem is correct.

Comment: So do we divide $\binom{7}{2}$ by $56$ which we got from (a) ?

Comment: That is correct.

Comment: Great!! For (c) we have $$P(X\geq 2)=1-P(X<2)=1-P(X=0)-P(X=1)$$ right? Then $P(X=0)$ is the probability that noone chooses the orange juice, right? So $1-p$, ten times, so $(1-p)^{10}$. And $P(X=1)=p\cdot (1-p)^9$.Is that correct?

Comment: Your approach is correct, as is your evaluation of $\Pr(X = 0)$.  For $\Pr(X = 1)$, you need to use the [Binomial distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution), which gives $\Pr(X = k) = \binom{n}{k}p^k(1 - p)^{n - k}$ for $n = 10$ and $k = 1$.  Therefore, you should have $\Pr(X = 1) = \binom{10}{1}p(1 - p)^9$.  The factor you were missing is the number of ways of selecting the one child who selects orange juice.

Comment: @MaryStar The one child who chose the orange juice in $P(X=1)$ can be anyone from those $10$ children so you need to multiply $^{10}C_1$ in your expression for the same. Rest is fine.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: For (b), my suggestion will be to find probability that none of the children pick orange juice. In other words they all pick $3$ juices from $7$ different juices (other than orange juice).

As there are $10$ different children, use the product rule to find probability that no child picks orange juice and then subtract from $1$ to find probability that at least one of them choose orange juice.

Comment: A nice approach, as usual.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig I saw a message from you and thought I had made another typo :) Thank you and thanks for all the corrections you keep suggesting from time to time!